# Failed to Run any "Model/Controller in Browser using YII and gii ?

Tags: php, yii, sqlyog

I am newbie in Php using YII and Gii when iam trying to open any model and controller file in browser i am getting error the console of error and code is:
**CODE:**

```
 <?php

 class UsersController extends Controller {

    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->render('index');
    }
public function actionLogIn() {
        if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
            $username = strtolower($_POST['user_name']);
                  $pass = MD5($_POST['password']);
                $record = Users::model()->find('user_name=:username and password=:pass and status=:status', array(':username' => $username, ':pass' => $pass, ':status' => 'ACTIVE'));
          if($record){

                $response['status'] = true;
                    $response['message'] = "Successfully Logged In.";
                    $response['user'] = $record;
          } else {
                    $response['status'] = false;
                    $response['message'] = "Username Or Password did not Match.";
                }
            echo CJSON::encode($response);
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the error which appears in browser 
  [image: Browser Result]
Can someone please point me what does this error mean  ?

Comment: you have to import classes in components folder. that's the default location for that class

Comment: any example how can i import classes ?

Comment: I believe that the right url is http://localhost/exampp/services

Answer (score 0):

try this url

```
localhost/projectName/moduleName/controllerName/actionName
```

Watching your question I think your are trying to use this Url

```
localhost/projectName/services/users
```

Comment: can you tell what url you are exactly running?

Comment: UsersNew is the "module name" , "UserController" is the controller name

Comment: its getting some problem to find Controller class may i need to define any controllers in Components/Controller.php file if yes then how to define ?

Comment: try this url localhost/examapp/usersNew/user/index

Comment: @Letmesee  Home About Contact Login
Home » Error
Error 404

Unable to resolve the request "usersNew/user/index".

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Yii!

> Can someone please point me what does this error mean ?

The php code in your `UsersController.php` is being parsed and it's seen that your class `UsersController` extends the class `Controller`, which it can't find because it hasn't been imported (along with the rest of the framework).

> i am trying to open any model and controller file in browser

If you want to test your `actionIndex()` method in your `UsersController` class (in your `UsersNew` module), you need to do it using this url:

`localhost/examapp/usersNew/users/index`

Make sure you have the urlmanager enabled (uncommented) in your config main.php file: `/protected/config/main.php`, like this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'showScriptName'=>false,
    'rules'=>array(
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
    ),
),
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:

When using the urlmanager, you should add a .htaccess file to the root containing the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Because you're using wamp, you should check that it has the rewrite_module enabled:

[image]